# JSON data not displaying in Ionic HTML file

Tags: json, angular, ionic4

I have got my data from my API and it is logged in the console. However, I am unable to access it through my HTML file. I'm not sure why it isn't working? (Looked at other questions and still no joy).

ts file

```
 patients: [];
 constructor(private viewService: ViewPatientService ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

html file

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients"> 
Name: {{patient.patients.data[0].FirstName}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Missing `this.patients = data` under subscribe?

Comment: what do you see in the console?

Comment: Thanks so much was your answer plus I had to put [data] in an array!

Answer (score 0):

Please note **data** should hold the patients array, if not add the property as needed.

```
patients: [];

constructor(private viewService: ViewPatientService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.patients = data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You haven't assigned the value to patients array

```
patients: [];


constructor(private viewService: ViewPatientService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(data => {
      **this.patients = data;**
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
patients: any;


constructor(private viewService: ViewPatientService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(data => {
      this.patients = [data];
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add some explanation of how this solves the problem. This will make your answer more useful and understandable to the OP and to others in the future. Thank you.